# Largeness of the set of zeroes of a Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**Definitions:**

A measurable subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ is said to be *mesoscopic* if there exists a continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(S)$ is Lebesgue measurable and has nonzero Lebesgue measure.

> **Question:** Is the set of zeroes of a Brownian motion almost surely a mesoscopic set?

*Remark: Note that there exist mesoscopic sets of Lebesgue measure zero - for example the Cantor set with $f$ being the Cantor staircase function.*

Comment: I think there is a "not" missing from this definition somewhere.

Comment: Ah corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the local time (at zero) maps the zero set of Brownian motion to an interval. See e.g. Lemma 6.9 page 159 in [1] for continuity.

[1] Brownian motion, by Peter Mörters and Yuval Peres. Cambridge University Press, 2010   https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that the local time was continuous. I somehow intuitively had in mind a jump process, but I guess it makes more sense that it would be continuous.